# Group by all full weeks between date period - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I know how to count number of weeks between two dates.

I have a date period (start date and end date).
Is it possible to get `Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>` or something where `item_1` is a start day of week and `item_2` is the end? I mean I finally want to see `List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>`.

For example my period is from 13/09/16 till 5/10/16
As a result I want to see a list with two corteges:

1. 19/09/16 - 25/09/16
2. 26/09/16 - 2/10/16

I have wrote a regular cycle for this but want to have LINQ.

```
for (var day = start.Date; day.Date <= end.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
{
    if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        if (day.AddDays(6) < end.Date)
            result.Add(Tuple.Create(day.Date, day.AddDays(6).Date));
    }
}
```

Also it would be nice to include culture info if a week starting from Sunday like in USA.

Comment: Let's see your attempt and maybe someone could help where it's not working?

Comment: @ScottPerham I have no idea how to exclude days before/after full week in one linq expression..

Comment: I think you meant -> for (var day = start.Date; day.Date <= end.Date; day = day.AddDays(1)) otherwise its an endless loop!

Comment: @Innat3 Yes, it is a misprint. Wrote the code in to the Stackoverflow edit form. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very crude... but try something like this:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("13/09/16");
DateTime end = DateTime.Parse("5/10/16");

CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

Enumerable.Range(0, (end - start).Days)
    .Where(x => start.AddDays(x).DayOfWeek == culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
    .Select(x => new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(start.AddDays(x), start.AddDays(x + 6)))
    .Where(x => x.Item2 < end);
```

This will enumerate to:

```
| index |  first  |  second |
-----------------------------
|   0   | 19/09/16| 25/09/16|
|   1   | 26/09/16| 2/10/16 |
```

Comment: Excellent! you just missed converting it into the a list :P List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> Weeks = Enumerable.Range(0, (end - start).Days)
                .Where(x => start.AddDays(x).DayOfWeek == culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
                .Select(x => new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(start.AddDays(x), start.AddDays(x + 6)))
                .Where(x => x.Item2 < end).ToList();

Comment: Actually... you'll notice that I didn't assign it to anything... therefore no "ToList()" required - it's only guidance to the answer :)

Comment: Looks like an answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Given a date you can determine the date when the week started by subtracting the first day of week from the day of week of the date. You then need to handle negative numbers in the case where the first day of week is Monday (1) and the day of week of the date is Sunday (0) as `0 - 1 = -1` and not 6. Here is a function that does that:

```
int GetDayOfWeekOffset(DateTime date, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
  return ((int) (date.DayOfWeek - cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek) + 7)%7;
}
```

So if the first day of the week (determined by `CultureInfo`) is Monday then the function will return 0, 1, ..., 6 for days Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday. When the first day of the week is Sunday then it will return 0, 1, ..., 6 for days Sunday, Monday, ..., Saturday.

You can subtract the number of days returned by the function to get the date a week started given a date in that week:

```
var firstWeekStart = startDate.AddDays(-GetDayOfWeekOffset(startDate, cultureInfo));
var lastWeekStart = endDate.AddDays(-GetDayOfWeekOffset(endDate, cultureInfo));
```

These two dates can be used to generate the desired list:

```
var weekCount = (int) (lastWeekStart - firstWeekStart).TotalDays/7 + 1;
var weeks = Enumerable
  .Range(0, weekCount)
  .Select(week => firstWeekStart.AddDays(7*week))
  .Where(weekStart => startDate <= weekStart && weekStart.AddDays(6) <= endDate)
  .Select(weekStart => Tuple.Create(weekStart, weekStart.AddDays(6)))
  .ToList();
```

Notice the `Where` clause that ensures that only weeks inside the range of dates determined by `startDate` and `endDate` are included.

This approach is more "efficient" compared to the answer provided by Scott as the implicit `foreach` loop enumerates weeks and not days (so up to 7 times fever iterations). However, "efficiency" probably doesn't really matter as long as you don't have to create a very long list of weeks.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I see what's you mean.